# How you can hide a partition on macOS?

Tags: security, partition, terminal

i wanted to know how you can hide a partition on macOS, however i read that in macOSX you could open the debugging menu in macOS's disk utility via terminal and it allowed you to hide partitions and i learned this ended up as a security measure from part of apple, I also know that you can hide partitions from the Finder using the chflag or SetFile command but if I type cd /Volumes and then ls in the terminal it shows me the partition immediately, while I would like it to be "a little more hidden", is there any other way to hide a partition from the Finder or a simple ls after two command lines?, I don't know if I explained myself well, I'm an absolute beginner and just wanted to know how to do it, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the reason you want to hide it and how would you use it as if hidden you could not access it?

Comment: @mmmmmm just deepening more on how to hide partitions on macOS, actually I would like to access it, the problem is that I currently know hiding methods that I mentioned before, however they are more “simplified” and not secure compared to when there was macOSX from what I've read, so I wanted to know if there was any other method to “better hide the partition”, obviously being able to access into it, but not simply with a cd and ls command, I don’t know if there is anything more complicated, sorry for my bad knowledge but I'm an absolute beginner, thanks.

Comment: WHat do you mean by hide? How will you access if not by cd and ls?

Comment: @mmmmmm by hiding I mean that it shouldn't shown in the finder and  it should be a little deeper to reach, perhaps with some more code (I don't know, it's just a supposition), but I think that typing a cd and ls command just after you have opened the terminal, it is not really hidden, in fact I wanted to know if there is currently other methods. I can make you an example with the mr robot series, did you watch it ?

Comment: Unix does not really work like that. Even if you can't cd to it an admin account can. I suspect a way might be to encrypt it and that will require a password to mount it.